# Automatically attach image to post if they have the same title

Tags: posts, attachments, media, library

I have 200 images in my WP install.

Currently, each image...

- has its own post (the post title is the same as the image title)
- is the featured image of that post
- is inserted into the post

However, the images are **not** attached to the post. By going to `Media > Library > Unattached`, all 200 images are there.

I know that I can manually attach them by going to `Edit Image > Search for post with same title > Attach` but that means I'd have to do it manually for 200 images. Is there a way for me to automate this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: attachment is handled by the `post_parent` property of the image. you could use `get_posts()` or `$wpdb` to loop through all attachments, find the corresponding post and update the attachment's `post_parent` value to that of the post's ID.

Comment: did you solved it? it would be nice for others and myself included to see a solution